# Functions in SKScene Class are not running

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

one of my VC's SceneEditViewController has a SKView that is presenting my SKScene AnimationInventory class. To present the AnimationInventory class, the user has to press the PreviewScene button. The SceneEditViewController class is attached to item 1 scene within a TabBarController.

However, after pressing the PreviewScene button, the class properties are being identified but my functions are not, not even a print statement is being displayed from my functions.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class SceneEditViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var animationScreen: SKView!

    @IBAction func previewScene(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let animationScene = AnimationInventory(size: CGSize(width:400, height:400))
        animationScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
        animationScene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        animationScene.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1.0)

        animationScreen.presentScene(animationScene, transition: transition)
    }

    //Additional code not include but can be if needed
}

class AnimationInventory: SKScene {
    func niceToMeetYou() {
        print("Code Run Check")
    }

    //MARK: Override functions
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        niceToMeetYou()
    }
}
```

Comment: you are calling a function named 'friend()' and printing out in a function named 'niceToMeetYou()' which is it?

Comment: Making an edit without acknowledging and explaining the code issues addressed in comments makes comments hard to follow and irrelevant!

Comment: @RonMyschuk I was trying to add an image as well but was taking too long, sorry. Just to confirm, I've updated the code to include niceToMeetYou() in the didMove override.

Comment: my mistake on my answer I misread you description

Comment: @RonMyschuk all good mate

Comment: Do you already have a scene presented? Are you trying to present your AnimationInventory on top of another scene?

Comment: @RonMyschuk no other scene is included at the moment. I have the SKView displayed but no scene presented by it yet.